# Java Library for 3-D Scatter Plotting With Text

Tags: java, 3d, plot

I am currently using `jmathplot` but I have IDs of my points and I want to display them above my ponts.

I also save the screen captures of my plots (I save `JFrame` as `.PNG`). Hence, I need that feature too.

Which library should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Orson Charts](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/) (a product of my company) will display item labels for any or all of the points in a 3D scatter plot.  It also has a tooltip mechanism to support regular Swing tooltips when hovering over a point in the scatter plot.  Here is a screenshot showing two points with item labels (in this particular demo, the user can click on points to show or hide the item labels - please excuse the faded look of the labels, they're a bit more legible when running the demo live and, in any case, all the colors can be customized):

[image: Screenshot of RangeMarkerDemo1.java]

The text of the labels is fully customisable via the API of course (using the [XYZItemLabelGenerator](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/javadoc/com/orsoncharts/label/XYZItemLabelGenerator.html) interface).